# Print range in excel vba

Tags: vba, printing, range

I have a pivot that returns data to letting me know what pages in a sheet in need to print. I am looking at using VBA to output based on the pivot. I can't get the range to work. I am I missing something?

Thanks

```
Sub RectangleRoundedCorners1_Click()

    If Range("M4").Value = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Pivot").PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:H35"
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut

        If Range("M5").Value = 2 Then Worksheets("Pivot").PageSetup.PrintArea = "A36:H71"
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut

            If Range("M6").Value = 3 Then
                Range("A72:H107").PrintOut

                If Range("M7").Value = 4 Then
                    Worksheets("Pivot").PageSetup.PrintArea = "A108:H143"
                    ActiveSheet.PrintOut

                    If Range("M8").Value = 5 Then
                        Range("A144:H179").PrintOut

                        If Range("M9").Value = 6 Then
                            Range("A180:H215").PrintOut

                            If Range("M10").Value = 7 Then
                                Range("A216:H251").PrintOut

                                If Range("M11").Value = 8 Then
                                    Range("A252:H287").PrintOut

                                    If Range("M12").Value = 9 Then
                                        Range("A288:H323").PrintOut

                                        If Range("M13").Value = 10 Then
                                            Range("A324:H359").PrintOut

                                            If Range("M14").Value = 11 Then

                                                Range("A360:H395").PrintOut
                                                If Range("M15").Value = 12 Then

                                                    Range("A396:H431").PrintOut
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of the code. You'll have to change the rest of them.

```
If Range("M6").Value = 3 Then
   Range("A72:H107").Select
   ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A72:H107"
   ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```